# How to reslove "socket.gaierror" error of python-smtplib?

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

Few hours back I have posted a post related to "Django email sending API" and its error. So I thought that first I should try something with  "smtplib". Unfortunately, after struggling with "smtplib", I realise that it will also not work,  because something is wrong with my code or my network or my machine which I am not able to figure out.

Can any body help me regarding to this?

As of now, after struggling a lot,  I have tried hundreds of  solution posted  here and there and also I have tried to resolve with myself but nothing is working in my case kindly help.

Code is given bellow.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

import socks



socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, "172.16.0.2", '8084')
socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)

#smtp = smtplib.SMTP()

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'my@yahoo.com'
msg['To'] = 'example@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com',465)
# identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
mailserver.ehlo()
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
# re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('my@yahoo.com', 'pswd12345678')

mailserver.sendmail('my@yahoo.com','example@gmail.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

This is the error coming again and again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_mail.py", line 21, in <module>
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com',465)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: I am facing the similar issue, any update on the issue?

Comment: @yashgarg this Quetion was posted by me long ago, though, I have resolved this error later on but now I forgot what exactly I did.

Comment: Not an issue. Do you happen to remember if there is a daily email limit in the smtplib.py

Comment: No I am sure that it was not relate to "daily email limit in the smtplib.py"

Answer (score 5):

This error is raised as the 'EMAIL_BACKEND' definition is missing from the settings file. Make sure that the settings.py file contains the following line:-

```
  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

IF you`re using the gmail account to set up a default interactive mail, use the following values:-

```
  EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
  EMAIL_PORT = 587 #PORT NO
  EMAIL_HOST_USER = #e-MAIL ID
  EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = #PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

My system had not a DNS configured and I resolved this issue configuring a google DNS or an openDNS.

Comment: Can your provide a link or walkthrough on how to do that?